# Can I make a subclass with Nodejs mongoose using extents?

Tags: node.js, class, mongoose, subclass

I even made classes. What I want to do is use a constructor.
I'd like to create a subclass.

ex)

```
class OrderLog {
        constructor(...args) {
           switch (this.planType) { 
            case 'test':
               // return new SubClass()  // // I want to return the subclass by condition
                break;
           }
         }
}
```

My code :

I created a class and ran loadClass on the schema. But I want to make OrderLog a structure that uses the constructor to return the subclass when I first call the class.

```
const { Schema } = require('mongoose');

const orderLogSchema = new Schema({
    userId: {type: String, required: false, index: true},
    orderPlanId: {type: String, required: false, index: true},
    orderId: {type: String, required: false, index: true},
    planType: {type: String, required: true, index: true},
    indicatorType: {type: String},
    bundle: {type: String},
    action: {type: String, required: true},
    orderContents: {type: String},
    createdAt: {type: Date, required: true},
});


class OrderLog {
    constructor(...args) {
    }

    static makeNew(orderLogForm){
        const saveOrderLogForm = {
            userId: orderLogForm.userId,
            orderPlanId: orderLogForm.orderPlanId,
            orderId: orderLogForm.id,
            planType: orderLogForm.planType,
            indicatorType: orderLogForm.indicatorType,
            bundle: orderLogForm.bundle,
            action: orderLogForm.action,
            orderContents: orderLogForm.orderContents,
            createdAt: orderLogForm.createdAt
        };
        const orderLog = new this(saveOrderLogForm)
        orderLog.save();
    }
}

orderLogSchema.loadClass(OrderLog);


module.exports = (connectionPool) => {
    let orderLogModel = connectionPool.model('OrderLog', orderLogSchema);
    return orderLogModel;
};
```